# ConcurrentHashMap vs Synchronized HashMap

Tags: java

What is the difference between using the wrapper class, `SynchronizedMap`, on a `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Is it just being able to modify the `HashMap` while iterating it (`ConcurrentHashMap`)?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Synchronized `HashMap`：

1. Each method is synchronized using an *`object level lock`*. So the get and put methods on synchMap acquire a lock.
2. Locking the entire collection is a performance overhead. While one thread holds on to the lock, no other thread can use the collection.

`ConcurrentHashMap` was introduced in JDK 5.

1. There is no locking at the object level,The locking is at a much finer granularity. For a `ConcurrentHashMap`, the locks may be at a *`hashmap bucket level`*.
2. The effect of lower level locking is that you can have concurrent readers and writers which is not possible for synchronized collections. This leads too much more scalability.
3. `ConcurrentHashMap` does not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it.

This article [Java 7: HashMap vs ConcurrentHashMap](https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-hashmap-vs)  is a very good read. Highly recommended.

Comment: So what is the different between `Hashtable` and `Synchronized HashMap` ?

Comment: Between a ConcurrentHashMap and a Synchronized HashMap, which one do you recommend?

Comment: It's worth mention that `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `size()` result could be out of date. `size()` is allowed to return an approximation instead of an exact count according to "Java Concurrency in Practice" book. So this method should be used carefully.

Comment: @roottraveller for Hashtable and Synchronized HashMap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875680/difference-between-hashtable-and-collections-synchronizedmaphashmap

Answer (score 90):

The short answer:

Both maps are thread-safe implementations of the `Map` interface. `ConcurrentHashMap` is implemented for higher throughput in cases where high concurrency is expected.

Brian Goetz's [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/index.html) on the idea behind `ConcurrentHashMap` is a very good read. Highly recommended.

Comment: What is this then?

HashMap: Note that this implementation is not synchronized

to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the map:

`Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: "Brian Goetz's article ... is a very good read."   -  And even more so is his "Java Concurrency in Practice" book .

Comment: The link to the article is broken

Answer (score 36):

`ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe without synchronizing the whole map. Reads can happen very fast while write is done with a lock.

Answer (score 34):

We can achieve thread safety by using both ConcurrentHashMap and synchronisedHashmap. But there is a lot of difference if you look at their architecture.

1. **synchronisedHashmap**

> It will maintain the lock at the object level. So if you want to perform any operation like put/get then you have to acquire the lock first. At the same time, other threads are not allowed to perform any operation. So at a time, only one thread can operate on this. So the waiting time will increase here. We can say that performance is relatively low when you are comparing with ConcurrentHashMap.

2. **ConcurrentHashMap**

> It will maintain the lock at the segment level. It has 16 segments and maintains the concurrency level as 16 by default. So at a time, 16 threads can be able to operate on ConcurrentHashMap. Moreover, read operation doesn't require a lock. So any number of threads can perform a get operation on it.
>
> If thread1 wants to perform put operation in segment 2 and thread2 wants to perform put operation on segment 4 then it is allowed here. Means, 16 threads can perform update(put/delete) operation on ConcurrentHashMap at a time.
>
> So that the waiting time will be less here. Hence the performance is relatively better than synchronisedHashmap.

Comment: Very nice explanation
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

`SynchronizedMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap` are both thread safe class and can be used in multithreaded application, the main difference between them is regarding how they achieve thread safety.

`SynchronizedMap` acquires lock on the entire Map instance , while `ConcurrentHashMap` divides the Map instance into multiple segments and locking is done on those.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are these segments in ConcurrentHashMap?

Answer (score 11):

Both are synchronized version of HashMap, with difference in their core functionality and their internal structure.

**ConcurrentHashMap** consist of internal segments which can be viewed as independent HashMaps  Conceptually.
All such segments can be locked by separate threads in high concurrent executions.
So, multiple threads can get/put key-value pairs from ConcurrentHashMap without blocking/waiting for each other.
This is implemented for higher throughput.

whereas

**Collections.synchronizedMap()**, we get a synchronized version of HashMap and it is accessed in blocking manner. This means if multiple threads try to access synchronizedMap at same time, they will be allowed to get/put key-value pairs one at a time in synchronized manner.

Answer (score 7):

`ConcurrentHashMap` uses finer-grained locking mechanism known as `lock stripping` to allow greater degree of shared access. Due to this it provides better **concurrency** and **scalability**.

Also iterators returned for `ConcurrentHashMap` are **weakly consistent** instead of **fail fast technique** used by Synchronized HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

Methods on `SynchronizedMap` hold the lock on the object, whereas in `ConcurrentHashMap` there's a concept of "lock striping" where locks are held on buckets of the contents instead. Thus improved scalability and performance.

Answer (score 2):

**ConcurrentHashMap :**

1)Both maps are thread-safe implementations of the Map interface.

2)ConcurrentHashMap is implemented for higher throughput in cases where high concurrency is expected.

3) There is no locking in object level.

**Synchronized Hash Map:**

1) Each method is synchronized using an object level lock.

Answer (score 1):

***ConcurrentHashMap*** allows concurrent access to data. Whole map is divided into segments.

Read operation ie. `get(Object key)` is not synchronized even at segment level.

But write operations ie. `remove(Object key), get(Object key)` acquire lock at segment level. Only part of whole map is locked, other threads still can read values from various segments except locked one.

**SynchronizedMap** on the other hand, acquire lock at object level. All threads should wait for current thread irrespective of operation(Read/Write).

Answer (score 1):

[A simple performance test for ConcurrentHashMap vs Synchronized HashMap](https://gist.github.com/CoderInOne/3e5bf2f179d29d5cdd426d133fbc0dbf)
. The test flow is calling `put` in one thread and calling `get` in three threads on `Map` concurrently. As @trshiv said, ConcurrentHashMap has higher throughput and speed for whose reading operation without lock. The result is when operation times is over `10^7`, ConcurrentHashMap is `2x` faster than Synchronized HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

**Synchronized HashMap**

1. **Lock mechanism** - It Locks the whole map, so Multiple threads can't access the map concurrently. So, performance is relatively less.

2.**Null key or Value** - It will allow null as a key or value.

3.**Concurrent modification exception** - Iterator return by synchronized map throws concurrent modification exception

**ConcurrentHashMap**

1.**Lock mechanism** -Locks the portion, Concurrent hashmap allows concurrent read and write. So performance is relatively better than a synchronized map

2.**Null key or Value** - It doesn't allow null as a key or value. If you use it will throw java.lang.**NullPointerException** at Runtime.

3.**Concurrent modification exception** - It doesn't throw concurrent modification exceptions.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Ex_ConcurrentHashMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        map.put("one", "one");
        map.put("two", "two");
        map.put("three", "three");
        System.out.println("1st  map : "+map);
        String key = null;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> itr : map.entrySet())
        {
            key = itr.getKey();
            if("three".equals(key))
            {
                map.put("FOUR", "FOUR");
            }
            System.out.println(key+" ::: "+itr.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("2nd  map : "+map);
        //map.put("FIVE", null);//java.lang.NullPointerException
        map.put(null, "FIVE");//java.lang.NullPointerException
        System.out.println("3rd  map : "+map);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Synchronized HashMap Example**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Ex_Synchronizedmap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        map.put("one", "one");
        map.put("two", "two");
        map.put("three", "three");
        map.put("FOUR", null);
        map.put(null, "FIVE");
        
        System.out.println("map : "+map);
        
        Map<String, String> map1 = 
                Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
        System.out.println("map1 : "+map1);
        
        String key = null;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> itr : map1.entrySet())
        {
            key = itr.getKey();
            if("three".equals(key))
            {
                map1.put("ABC", "ABC");
            }
            System.out.println(key+" ::: "+itr.getValue());
        }
        
        System.out.println("New Map :: "+map1);
        
        
        
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = map1.entrySet().iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            if(i == 1)
            {
                map1.put("XYZ", "XYZ");
            }
            Entry<String, String> next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(next.getKey()+" :: "+next.getValue());
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per java doc's

> Hashtable and Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap()) are
>   synchronized. But ConcurrentHashMap is "concurrent".
>
> A concurrent collection is thread-safe, but not governed by a single exclusion lock.
>
> In the particular case of ConcurrentHashMap, it safely permits
>   any number of concurrent reads as well as a tunable number of
>   concurrent writes. "Synchronized" classes can be useful when you need
>   to prevent all access to a collection via a single lock, at the
>   expense of poorer scalability.
>
> In other cases in which multiple
>   threads are expected to access a common collection, "concurrent"
>   versions are normally preferable. And unsynchronized collections are
>   preferable when either collections are unshared, or are accessible
>   only when holding other locks.