# Difference between Hashtable and Collections.synchronizedMap(HashMap)

Tags: java, collections, synchronization, hashmap, hashtable

As far as I know, [`java.util.Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) synchronizes each and every method in the [`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, while [`Collections.synchronizedMap(hash_map)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) returns a wrapper object containing synchronized methods delegating calls to the actual `hash_map` (correct me if I am wrong).

**I have two questions :**

1. What difference does it make to synchronize each and every method and to have a wrapper class? What are the scenarios to choose one over the other?
2. What happens when we do `Collections.synchronizedMap(hash_table)`? Will this be equal to simply using a normal `java.util.Hashtable`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of *that* question. This is comparing the synchronized wrapper over a HashMap (or HashTable) with a HashTable.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there are differences in performance, which none of the current answers address. Calling methods of a `Collections.synchronizedMap` via a variable of type Map means there are 2 interface virtual calls before you get to the implementation, whereas with Hashtable, there is at most 1 virtual call, and you could declare your variable as type Hashtable directly, and do it with 0 virtual calls. But perhaps HashMap differs in other ways that make it faster overall.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are the answers I've gotten from a bit of (hopefully correct) research:

1. Both provide the same degree of synchronization. If you were to wrap `Hashtable` through Collections.synchronized you would have the same degree, but with another redundant layer, of synchronization.
2. The main difference between `Hashtable` and `Collections.synchronizedMap(HashMap)` exist more at the API level. Because `Hashtable` is part of Java's legacy code, you'll see that the `Hashtable` API is enhanced to implement the `Map` interface, to become part of Java's collections framework. This means that if you were to wrap `Hashtable` through `Collections.synchronizedMap()`, the API of the wrapped `Hashtable` would become limited to the `Map` API. So if the API of `Hashtable` is encompassed in your definition of **behavior**, then it is obviously altered/limited.

Comment: adding to it, Hashtable methods are synchronized whereas Synchronized map's method implementations have synchronized maps on a mutex.

Answer (score 75):

One more difference that I can find at the implementation of both the classes is as follows:

•   The `Hashtable` class has all its methods synchronized i.e. the locking is done at the method level and hence one can say that the mutex is **always** at the `Hashtable` object (**`this`**) level.

•   The method `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` returns an instance of `SynchronizedMap` which is an inner class to the `Collections` class. This class has all its methods in a `Synchronized` block with a mutex. The difference lies in the mutex here. The inner class `SynchronizedMap` has two constructors, one which takes only `Map` as an argument and another which takes a `Map` and an `Object` (mutex) as an argument. By default if one uses the first constructor of passing only a `Map`, *`this`* is used as a mutex. Though, the developer is allowed to pass another object of mutex as a second argument by which the lock on the `Map` methods would be only on that `Object` and hence less restrictive than `Hashtable`.

•   Hence, `Hashtable` uses method level synchronization but `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` provides a flexibility to developer lock on provided mutex with `Synchronized` block.

Comment: What a beautiful answer, underlining what remain untouched otherwise in rest answers. +1

Comment: Extra constructor and synchronization at block level (unlike method level for HashTable) are the keys.

Comment: This is really interesting information, but the inner SynchronizedMap class is private, and there is no static method corresponding to the version of the constructor that accepts a mutex object as an argument, so the developer cannot really provide a custom mutex, right?

Comment: @CarLuva You are right. I don't see any method exposed to use the second contructor.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that `Hashtable` and `Collections.synchronizedMap`  are both blocking collections and are almost the same under the hood?

Comment: but how 2nd contructor will be called, we are only doing Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829463/purpose-of-overloaded-constructor-in-synchronizedmap-class/50829585#50829585

Answer (score 4):

> The first associative collection class to appear in the Java class
> library was Hashtable, which was part of JDK 1.0. Hashtable provided
> an easy-to-use, thread-safe, associative map capability, and it was
> certainly convenient. However, the thread-safety came at a price --
> all methods of Hashtable were synchronized. At that time, uncontended
> synchronization had a measurable performance cost. The successor to
> Hashtable, HashMap, which appeared as part of the Collections
> framework in JDK 1.2, addressed thread-safety by providing an
> unsynchronized base class and a synchronized wrapper,
> Collections.synchronizedMap. Separating the base functionality from
> the thread-safety Collections.synchronizedMap allowed users who needed
> synchronization to have it, but users who didn't need it didn't have
> to pay for it.
>
> The simple approach to synchronization taken by both Hashtable and
> synchronizedMap -- synchronizing each method on the Hashtable or the
> synchronized Map wrapper object -- has two principal deficiencies. It
> is an impediment to scalability, because only one thread can access
> the hash table at a time. At the same time, it is insufficient to
> provide true thread safety, in that many common compound operations
> still require additional synchronization. While simple operations such
> as get() and put() can complete safely without additional
> synchronization, there are several common sequences of operations,
> such as iteration or put-if-absent, which still require external
> synchronization to avoid data races.

The following link is the source and has more information: [Concurrent Collections Classes](https://web.archive.org/web/20121106191331/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html)

Comment: The second paragraph says that `Hashtable` and `synchronizedMap`  is the same thing. Which means we haven't answered the question at all: What's their difference?

Answer (score 4):

Another point of difference to note is that **HashTable** does not allow null keys or values whereas **HashMap** allows one null key and any number of null values. Since **synchronizedMap** is wrapper over HashMap, its behavior with respect to null keys and values is same as HashMap.

Comment: Irrelevant answer

Comment: This directly answers the question posed in the title, which certainly makes it relevant. This is true even if the question body poses a more specific set of questions. Remember that people often find and read questions based on the title, and this answer is productive for those people. Losing this answer would reduce the usefulness of this question in aggregate.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is not all at the obvious API level and there are many subtleties at the implementation level. For example, `Hashtable` doesn't sport `HashMap`'s advanced recalculation of supplied keys' hashcodes that reduces hash collisions. On the other hand, `Hashtable#hashCode()` avoids infinite recursion for self-referential hashtables to allow "certain 1.1-era applets with self-referential hash tables to work".

In general, though, one shouldn't count on `Hashtable` receiving any further improvements or refinements beyond basic correctness and backward compatibility. It is considered a relic from the deep Java past.

Comment: The question is not about comparing hashtable and hashmap

Comment: Yes it is: `synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>())` vs. `new Hashtable<>()`.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious (or being plain wrong) isn't the difference that

> The synchronization wrappers add automatic synchronization
>   (thread-safety) to an arbitrary collection

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html and continues to say

> A collection created in this fashion is every bit as thread-safe as a
>   normally synchronized collection, such as a Vector.

You may like to see this thread for issues regarding HashMaps and concurrency - [Hashmap concurrency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003026/hashmap-concurrency-issue) (or you are possibly very much aware of them already). A good example is:

> The conditions you describe will not be satisfied by HashMap. Since
>   the process of updating a map is not atomic you may encounter the map
>   in an invalid state. Multiple writes might leave it in a corrupted
>   state. ConcurrentHashMap (1.5 or later) does what you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1003071/201648

I guess in terms of "when should I use this" I would tend to use the syncronised collection where concurrency is required, otherwise you may be creating more work for yourself (see below).

In terms of altering the behavior

> If an explicit iterator is used, the iterator method must be called
>   from within the synchronized block. Failure to follow this advice may
>   result in nondeterministic behavior

There are more consequences of using synchronization given at the (Oracle) link provided.