# HashTable synchronized methods and race conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition, synchronized

I am trying to get a grip on Collections here and found an article at [Race condition](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/what-is-race-condition-in.html)

It states that the below code may lead to race condition :

```
if (! hashtable.contains(key)) {
  hashtable.put(key, value);
}
```

I understood the explanation there to a certain extent but I have a doubt that since the methods of HashTable are synchronized, how is it possible that while thread1 is executing the put() method acquiring the lock on the entire Hashtable, other thread2 can execute the containskey() method? Aren't both these methods synchronized on the hashtable lock?

Comment: and what if the thread 1 is already AFTER checking IF condition but BEFORE execution put?
In this case it is not inside any synchronizatoion

Comment: "Aren't both these methods synchronized on the hashtable lock?" Yes, but the lock is released in between the invocation of the two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is it possible that while thread1 is executing the `put()` method acquiring the lock on the entire Hashtable, other thread2 can execute the `containskey()` method?

It's not possible.  The issue here is not about `Hashtable` class itself which, as you point out, is a synchronized class so will not be corrupted.  The race condition is that thread-A may test for a key that doesn't exist.  But before it can do the put, thread-B tests for the same key that still doesn't exist.  Then both threads put the same value into the table with one of them overwriting the other.  This is the race.

```
1   if (! hashtable.contains(key)) {
2       hashtable.put(key, value);
3   }
```

To enumerate the race more completely:

1. Thread-A calls `hashtable.contains("foo")` which returns false on line #1.
2. Thread-B runs then also calls `hashtable.contains("foo")` which also returns false on line #1.
3. Thread-A calls `hashtable.put("foo", "bar")` on line 2.
4. Thread-B calls `hashtable.put("foo", "baz")` on line 2.

If this happens in this order (and it certainly can), then Thread-B will overwrite Thread-A's value for `"foo"`.  `Hashtable` isn't corrupted but the overwrite may not have been expected by the logic of the code.  It might also happen that 4 and 3 are reversed so Thread-A would overwrite Thread-B's value for `"foo"`.  The nature of a race condition is that thread run order cannot be predicted and to ensure the right logic you need to apply specific locking.

Btw, `Hashtable` is an old class and has been superseded by `ConcurrentHashMap`.  But the race condition would still exist with `ConcurrentHashMap` although it *does* have atomic operations like [`concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) for this reason.  See [`ConcurrentMap` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).

Answer (score 3):

The synchronization on `HashTable` is per method: the lock is acquired and held only for the duration of the method invocation.

The code here is equivalent to:

```
boolean contains;
synchronized (hashtable) {
  contains = hashtable.contains(key);
}

if (!contains) {
  synchronized (hashtable) {
    hashtable.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

It is entirely possible that another thread interleaves between these two synchronized blocks, resulting in the race condition.

It is worth noting that `HashTable` is effectively deprecated, and only retained for legacy reasons. More modern alternatives would be `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>())` (which behaves basically the same from a synchronization perspective; [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875680/difference-between-hashtable-and-collections-synchronizedmaphashmap)), or `ConcurrentHashMap`, which provides methods to update the map atomically, e.g.

```
concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(key, value);
```

Java 8 maps do provide `computeIfAbsent`, but it is not guaranteed to be atomic, except for in `ConcurrentHashMap`.