# Purpose of overloaded constructor in SynchronizedMap class

Tags: java, collections

In `Collections` class, class `SynchronizedMap` has two constructors. One takes only a `map` instance and another with a `map` and a `mutex`.

```
    SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m) {
        this.m = Objects.requireNonNull(m);
        mutex = this;
    }

    SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m, Object mutex) {
        this.m = m;
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }
```

However, SynchronizedMap class is a private static class and only way to access it using provided wrapper method:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m) {
    return new SynchronizedMap<>(m);
}
```

As understood from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875680/difference-between-hashtable-and-collections-synchronizedmaphashmap), the idea of the second constructor to use user-supplied `mutex` other than `this`. Now, since the wrapper method is the only way to get an instance of `SynchronizedMap` (which takes only a map object) , what is the purpose of this second overloaded constructor?

Comment: Seems like it gives the map user to specify the object on which synchronization is done (which otherwise defaults to the map instance itself).

Comment: Make up your mind. Either it is static or it is inner. `static inner` is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP Edited. I meant its static nested class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used e.g. in `SynchronizedSortedMap` which extends `SynchronizedMap` when creating submap view.

```
 public SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                return new SynchronizedSortedMap<>(
                    sm.subMap(fromKey, toKey), mutex);
            }
        }
```

To share the same mutex.