# synchronize a method by achieving better performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class that is being called by multiple threads on multi core machine. I want to make it thread safe.

`add` method will be called by multiple threads. And if key exists, just append the current value to new value otherwise just put key and value in the map.

Now to make it thread safe, I was planning to synchronize `add` method but it will destroy performance. Is there any better way by which we can achieve better performance without synchronizing `add` method?

```
class Test {
  private final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public void add(int key, int value) {
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
      int val = map.get(key);
      map.put(key, val + value);
      return;
    }
    map.put(key, value);
  }

  public Object getResult() {
    return map.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentHashMap vs Synchronized HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291836/concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronized-hashmap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
class Test {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void add(int key, int value) {
        map.merge(key, value, Integer::sum);
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return map.toString();
    }
}
```

Java 7 solution if you absolutely can't use synchronized (or, you absolutely cannot lock explicitly):

```
class Test {
    final Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void add(int key, int value) {
        get(key).addAndGet(value);
    }

    private AtomicInteger get(int key) {
        AtomicInteger current = map.get(key);

        if (current == null) {
            AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

            current = map.putIfAbsent(key, ai);

            if (current == null) {
                current = ai;
            }
        }

        return current;
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        return map.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is merge doing behind the scene? And if we don't need to use merge then how can we do in old fashion way?

Comment: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1960 it's using CAS.  "don't need to use merge" -> " Is there any better way by which we can achieve better performance without synchronizing add method?". That's how you do it

Comment: Yeah agreed but I was asking instead of using merge feature can we do it in Java 7 as well in old fashion way?

Comment: If you are dead set on not using synchronized or any explicit look, see answer edit.

Answer (score 4):

> *but it will destroy performance*

It likely wouldn't *destroy* performance. It will reduce it some, with further reduction if there is a high collision rate.

> *Is there any better way by which we can achieve better performance?*

Yes, use [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) (Java 8+). Quoting the javadoc:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null.

*Example:*

```
public void add(int key, int value) {
    map.merge(key, value, (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

Or using a *method reference* to [`sum(int a, int b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#sum-int-int-) instead of a *lambda expression*:

```
public void add(int key, int value) {
    map.merge(key, value, Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: How can we do this in Java 7? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @flash In Java 7 you do it with `synchronized` (yet another good reason to upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

`synchronized` causes a bottleneck only when you run an expensive operation holding a lock.
In your case by adding a `synchronized` you are doing:
1. check a hashmap for existence of a key
2. get the value mapped to that key
3. do an addition and put the result back to the hashmap.

All these operations are super cheap `O(1)` and unless you are using some strange pattern for the keys which are integers it should be very unlikely that you can get some degenerate performance due to collisions.

I would suggest if you can't use `merge` as the other answers point out, to just `synchronize`. You should be considered so much about performance only in critical hotpaths and after you have actually profiled that there is an issue there